# Class Assign Based on Column Values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataset like the following:

```
a <- structure(list(ID = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9"), 
                    E = c(1, 0, 0, 0,4, 4, 3, 0,1), 
                    W = c(0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 4,1), 
                    N = c(1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 3, 7,1), 
                    S=c(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0,1)), 
               .Names = c("ID", "E", "W", "N", "S"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
a
  ID E W N S
1 a1 1 0 1 0
2 a2 0 3 0 0
3 a3 0 2 2 0
4 a4 0 0 0 2
5 a5 4 3 3 1
6 a6 4 3 4 1
7 a7 3 3 3 3
8 a8 0 4 7 0
9 a9 1 1 1 1
```

I like to create a `class` column, that will show the `column name` based on the maximum number for each row. For example, the second row with ID `a2` has a *maximum value* 3 for `W` column. The class will be `W` and max will be 3. When a tie happens **in the maximum values**, it will include all the tied column names. For example, for row 1 (`ID=a1`), both column `E` and column `N` has the same **maximum value**, so the class will be defined as `E-N`, and max will be 1.

I have started with `melt` function:

```
library(reshape2)
a1= melt(a, id=c("ID"))
head(a1)
  ID variable value
1 a1        E     1
2 a2        E     0
3 a3        E     0
4 a4        E     0
5 a5        E     4
6 a6        E     4
```

The final output will be:

```
  ID   Class Max
1 a1     E-N   1
2 a2       W   3
3 a3     W-N   2
4 a4       S   2
5 a5       E   4
6 a6     E-N   4
7 a7 E-W-N-S   3
8 a8       N   7
9 a9 E-W-N-S   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** An option would be to `gather` into 'long' format, grouped by 'ID', `filter` the rows having `max` 'val', then `summarize` by `paste`ing the 'key' and take the `first` of 'val'

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(a, key, val, -ID) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(val == max(val)) %>% 
    summarise(Class = str_c(key, collapse="-"), Max = first(val))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#  ID    Class     Max
#  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#1 a1    E-N         1
#2 a2    W           3
#3 a3    W-N         2
#4 a4    S           2
#5 a5    E           4
#6 a6    E-N         4
#7 a7    E-W-N-S     3
#8 a8    N           7
#9 a9    E-W-N-S     1
```

---

**2)** Or another option in `tidyverse` without reshaping

```
a %>% 
  mutate(out = select(., -1)  %>%
                  pmap(.,  ~ c(...) %>%
                   keep(. == max(.)) %>%
                  {tibble(Class = str_c(names(.), collapse='-'),
                          Max = first(.))})) %>%
  unnest
#   ID E W N S   Class Max
#1 a1 1 0 1 0     E-N   1
#2 a2 0 3 0 0       W   3
#3 a3 0 2 2 0     W-N   2
#4 a4 0 0 0 2       S   2
#5 a5 4 3 3 1       E   4
#6 a6 4 3 4 1     E-N   4
#7 a7 3 3 3 3 E-W-N-S   3
#8 a8 0 4 7 0       N   7
#9 a9 1 1 1 1 E-W-N-S   1
```

---

**3)** Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(a), id.var = 'ID')[, {
     dat <- .SD[value == max(value)]
 .(Class = paste(dat$variable, collapse='-'), Max = dat$value[1])}, by = ID]
```

NOTE: This gives the OP's expected output

---

**4)** Or using `base R`

```
Max <- do.call(pmax, a[-1])
Class <-  tapply(names(a)[-1][col(a[-1]) *NA^(a[-1] != Max)], 
     c(row(a[-1])), FUN = function(x)  paste(na.omit(x), collapse='-'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Base R approach using `apply` would be to find the `max` in each row and find the corresponding column names.

```
a[c("max", "class")] <- t(apply(a[-1], 1, function(x) {
      val <- max(x)
      c(val, paste(names(a)[-1][x == val], collapse = "-"))
}))

a[c(1, 6, 7)]
#  ID   max   class
#1 a1     1     E-N
#2 a2     3       W
#3 a3     2     W-N
#4 a4     2       S
#5 a5     4       E
#6 a6     4     E-N
#7 a7     3 E-W-N-S
#8 a8     7       N
#9 a9     1 E-W-N-S
```

You could also get the column name by using `which` (as suggested by @tmfmnk), replace the last line in `apply` call by

```
c(val, paste(names(which(x == val)), collapse = "-"))
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think you can slightly improve it by `a[c("max", "class")] <- t(apply(a[-1], 1, function(x) {
 val <- max(x)
 c(val, paste(names(which(x == val)), collapse = "-"))
}))`.

Comment: @tmfmnk yes, that is a valid suggestion as well. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, It is a really nice solution, +1 :)